# Regex match in null bash string

Tags: regex, bash

In bash shell

```
testvar=

echo $testvar

[[ $testvar =~ ^M* ]] && echo "foo"
foo
```

Isn't the regex pattern matching strings starting with 'M', followed by anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO * means 0 or more so the empty string will be matched, add a mandatory M or use the + instead of * and it will do what you want.

Your test should look like:.

```
 [[ $testvar =~ ^MM* ]] && echo "foo"
```

or

```
 [[ $testvar =~ ^M+ ]] && echo "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the `+` solution but how do you make `M` "mandatory"?

Comment: by adding one M before the M* :) hence MM* you could have put any letter there really, but in your case that says, the pattern start with an M character and then M* says, zero or more M characters :)

Answer (score 0):

To match a string starting with `M` you have two options:

```
[[ $testvar = M* ]] # use glob pattern matching
```

or

```
[[ $testvar =~ ^M ]] # use a regular expression
```

The key problem with your attempt is that you've put the `*` directly after the `M`, which matches zero or more Ms at the start of the string (i.e. anything). The pattern I have used matches any string with an M at the start.